# RPN calculator with interactive and non-interactive modes

Tags: ruby, error-handling, console, calculator

While writing [this review](/a/91199/9357), I edited the  code until it became something quite different from the original.  In addition to the issues I mentioned, I ended up adding features:

- More operators / commands, including trigonometry in degree and radian modes.
- Support for multiple commands on a line, separated by whitespace.  Each line is transactional: if any part fails, the stack remains unchanged.
- A rudimentary help system, while maintaining a spartan interface.
- Readline support with tab completion when running in a TTY, and a quiet mode for accepting input from a pipe.

Concerns:

- I overrode `Array#dup` to do something completely different.
- In interactive mode, I want all output on stdout. In non-interactive mode, I want only the real output on stdout, and only critical error messages on stderr. The switching mechanism for the two modes seems cumbersome.

```
require 'readline'

# Mixin for an Array
module RPNOperators
  def +; push(pop + pop); end
  def -; push(-pop + pop); end
  def *; push(pop * pop); end
  def /; push(1.0 / pop * pop); end
  def ^; x = pop; push(pop ** x); end

  def deg(quiet=false)
    @conv = Math::PI / 180
    info 'In degree mode. (Use the "rad" command to switch to radian mode)' unless quiet
  end

  def rad(quiet=false)
    @conv = 1.0
    info 'In radian mode. (Use the "deg" command to switch to degree mode)' unless quiet
  end

  def pi;       push(Math::PI); end
  def cos;      push(Math.cos(pop * @conv)); end
  def sin;      push(Math.sin(pop * @conv)); end
  def tan;      push(Math.tan(pop * @conv)); end
  def acos;     push(Math.acos(pop) / @conv); end
  def asin;     push(Math.asin(pop) / @conv); end
  def atan;     push(Math.atan(pop) / @conv); end

  def e;        push(Math::E); end
  def chs;      push(-pop); end
  def inv;      push(1.0 / pop); end
  def cbrt;     push(Math::cbrt(pop)); end
  def sqrt;     push(Math::sqrt(pop)); end
  def ln;       push(Math::log(pop)); end
  def log;      push(Math::log10(pop)); end

  def clear;    super; end
  def drop;     pop; end
  def dup;      x = pop; push(x); push(x); end
  def roll;     unshift(pop); end
  def rolld;    push(shift); end
  def swap;     x = pop; y = pop; push(x); push(y); end

  def quit
    throw :quit
  end

  def help(stream=$stdout)
    stream.puts "Available commands:"
    stream.puts RPNOperators.public_instance_methods.join(' ')
    stream.puts
    if deg? then deg else rad end
  end

  private
  def deg?;     @conv != 1.0; end
  def rad?;     @conv == 1.0; end

  def info(s)
    puts s
  end
end

class RPNCalculator
  class InvalidCommand < Exception; end
  class StackUnderflowError < Exception; end

  class Stack < Array
    include RPNOperators

    def initialize(*args)
      super
      rad(true)
    end

    def pop(*n)
      raise StackUnderflowError.new if (n[0] || 1) > size
      super
    end

    def shift(*n)
      raise StackUnderflowError.new if (n[0] || 1) > size
      super
    end
  end

  def initialize
    @stack = Stack.new
    Readline.completion_proc = proc do |s|
      available_commands.grep(/^#{Regexp.escape(s)}/)
    end
  end

  def run
    catch(:quit) do
      loop do
        case input = prompt('> ')
        when nil
          throw :quit
        when /\s/
          command(*input.split(/\s+/))
        else
          command(input)
        end
      end
    end
    raise @error if @error
  end

  def command(*cmds)
    error_stream = $stdin.tty? ? $stdout : $stderr
    last_command = nil
    begin
      transaction do
        cmds.each do |cmd|
          last_command = cmd
          case cmd
          when /\A[+-]?\d*\.?\d+\Z/
            @stack.push(cmd.to_f)
          else
            if available_commands.include?(cmd)
              @stack.send(cmd.to_sym)
            else
              raise InvalidCommand.new
            end
          end
        end
      end
    rescue InvalidCommand
      error_stream.puts "Invalid input: \"#{last_command}\""
      @stack.help(error_stream)
      error_stream.puts
      error_stream.puts "Stack (top to bottom):"
    rescue StackUnderflowError
      error_stream.puts "#{last_command}: not enough operands"
    rescue Exception => e
      error_stream.puts e
    end
    display
  end

  def available_commands
    @available_cmds ||= RPNOperators.public_instance_methods(false).map { |sym| sym.to_s }
  end

  private
  def prompt(s)
    input = $stdin.tty? ? Readline.readline(s, true) : gets
    input.nil? ? nil : input.strip
  end

  def display
    puts @stack.reverse.map { |n| '%-8g' % n }.join('    ')
  end

  def transaction
    begin
      # Can't use @stack.dup, which has been overridden to do something else!
      saved_stack = @stack.clone
      @error = nil
      yield
    rescue Exception => e
      @error = e
      @stack = saved_stack
      raise
    end
  end
end

begin
  RPNCalculator.new.run
rescue Exception
  exit(1)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neat! I'm digging the dual TTY/pipe support, although it does introduce some complexity. My gut feeling is that I'd probably prefer a calculator object that is agnostic about the source of its input and the destination of its output, but which can be subclassed as necessary.

But you've chosen this direction, and I'm not saying the alternative would necessarily be nicer, so I'll take it as given, and focus on the internals.

- Between `RPNOperators` and `Stack`'s own methods do you even need to subclass `Array`? Or would it be neater to simply let `Stack` be a plain object that wraps an array? I'm only asking because subclassing array means `Stack` inherits *a lot* of methods, not all of which are necessarily desirable.

  But it's your call; the argument can be made either way. Personally, I just prefer specialized APIs and object composition, to "crowded" APIs caused by subclassing very generic classes like `Array`. But it's as much opinion as anything.

  A compromise might be to wrap the array, and use [`Forwardable`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) to delegate relevant methods to it with minimal hassle. No need to duplicate the `Array` methods that you *do* want.

  In any event, *not* subclassing `Array` would of course avoid (most) violations of the Liskov principle. You'd still be overriding `#dup` from `Object`, but you'd avoid overriding `#+`, `#-`, and `#*` from `Array`.
- `Stack#pop` and `Stack#shift`
  <strike>Instead of making them variadic, it'd be nicer to define the parameter of each with a default value (`n = 1`), since that's what appears to be intended. And the super methods aren't variadic either.</strike>
  *Edit:* I was wrong here. As pointed out in the comments, passing an argument to `Array#pop` causes it to always return an array, even if `n = 1`. So `Array#pop` is actually 0-1 variadic, but the closest you can get is to make a 0-n variadic. So, with that in mind, I'll instead recommend `n.first` instead of `n[0]` - just to still recommend something :)
  Also, note that `super` will still complain if *more* than 1 argument is passed.
- `Readline.completion_proc`
  You could do `available_commands.select { |cmd| cmd.start_with?(s) }` - seems more straightforward to me than interpolating a regex with an escaped string.
- `#command`
  This is a rather large method. A lot of is of course the exception handling, but it's also got a lot of nesting.

  One thing you might do right away is to pull the `if..else` out of the `case` statement's own `else` branch:

  ```
  case cmd
  when /\A[+-]?\d*\.?\d+\Z/ # Use a named constant instead?
    @stack.push(cmd.to_f)
  when *available_commands  # splat!
    @stack.send(cmd.to_sym)
  else
    raise InvalidCommand.new
  end
  ```

  I'd also suggest making your custom exception classes take a constructor argument (or several), so you can pass the invalid command and possibly other pieces of state along with the exception, rather than rely on the local `last_command` variable. (You could also be cheeky and do `raise cmd`, and then do `rescue RuntimeError => failed_command`, but that's pretty hacky.)

  You can also avoid a level of nesting since `rescue` statements don't need to be in an explicit `begin...end` block, and you have `ensure`:

  ```
  def command(*cmds)
    # ...
  rescue InvalidCommand
    # ...
  rescue StackUnderflowError
    # ...
  rescue Exception => e
    # ...
  ensure
    display
  end
  ```

  Lastly, and this is just because I like short methods, you could extract the "meat" (the case statement) into a private `#eval_command` (or something) method, so the transaction block becomes just:

  ```
  transaction do
    cmds.each(&method(:eval_command))
  end
  ```
- Exception classes
  Just a minor naming thing, but I'd either drop the `-Error` suffix from `StackUnderflowError` or add it to `InvalidCommand`, just to keep them consistent.
- stdout/stderr
  Unless I'm mistaken, `$stdin.tty?` isn't likely to change during the lifetime of an `RPNCalculator` object. So you could set the output and error streams as instance variables in the constructor.

  You could also add a (private) `#warn` method which would shadow the global `Object#warn`, writing to either stderr or stdout as necessary. It would let you call the more "symmetrical" methods `puts` and `warn`, instead of `puts` and `error_stream.puts`.
- `#available_commands`
  Tiny, tiny thing, but `.map { |sym| sym.to_s }` can be just `.map(&:to_s)`.
- Overriding `#dup`
  As mentioned, you can't completely avoid overriding a `#dup` method because your class will always inherit it from `Object`. Though I suppose you call the command something other than `dup` and solve the problem that way ;)

Comment: Part of my thinking for this `Stack` design is for `RPNOperators` to get stack operations like `push`, `pop`, `shift`, `unshift`, and `clear` in a compact way.

Comment: `[1337].pop(1)` doesn't behave the same as `[1337].pop`. I was trying to preserve that behaviour.

Comment: @200_success re `Stack < Array`: I figured as much, and it does make a lot of sense. As mentioned, the wrap-vs-subclass it's as much about my personal opinion as anything. Re `pop`: You're right - my mistake. I'll edit.